# How do I build a Perl hash in C, using SWIG?

Tags: c, perl, swig

I'm trying to create a Perl hash from within a C library. Here's what I've got so far:

```
static void add_string_to_perl_hash ( HV *hv, char * key, char *value ) {

SV *obj = sv_2mortal(newSVpv(value, 0));

hv_store(hv, (const char *)key, strlen (key), obj, 0);

SvREFCNT_inc(obj);

}

SV * do_get_test_hash () {

    static char *foo ="foo";
    static char *bar ="bar";

    HV *hv;

    hv = newHV();
    add_string_to_perl_hash ( hv, "foo",   foo);
    add_string_to_perl_hash ( hv, "bar",   bar);

    return sv_2mortal(newRV_noinc((SV*)hv));
}
```

Trying it out: I don't get anything that makes any sense to me:

```
use testlib;
use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper (testlib::do_get_test_hash());

$VAR1 = bless( do{\(my $o = 5359872)}, '_p_SV' );
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at Example 6 of [perlxstut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxstut.html). It creates a bunch of hashes and adds them to an array. At the end, it returns a reference to the array. It would work practically the same if you returned a hash.

Comment: Thanks. This had the details I needed.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you must push the value you want to return onto the stack, not return it from the function, but I am used to XS rather than SWIG.

Comment: Does this imply I have to use assembler to push it onto the stack?  (bleah!)  Or is there some other mechanism?

Comment: Hmmm. After reading more in perlguts and perlxstut, I realize you're talking about pushing it on to the Perl stack.  I tried 

    XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newRV_noinc((SV *) hv))); 

But get a compile error for the line:
    proc/tools.c: In function `do_get_test_hash':
    proc/tools.c:306: error: `sp' undeclared (first use in this function)

Not sure what this is about...